# Delete table view cell via button in it

Tags: swift, uitableview, return, tableview, guard

I want to delete a tableview cell row when the button deleteButton is triggered. You can see exactly what I am looking for in the gif below. When the user taps the deleteButton is should call the func didDelete. Right now if you press the button nothing happens. And every time the delete button is called it should delete the cell which the button was in.

[Gif of TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o44yb.gif)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    
    private var myArray: [String] = ["First"]
    
    
     var myTableView =  UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
        myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       
        myTableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
   

               
               NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                   myTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.90),
                   myTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
                   myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                   myTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),



               ])
        
    }
    
   

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
        print("Value: \(myArray[indexPath.row])")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.label.text = ""

        
        cell.buttonTapCallback = { [weak self] in
               guard let self = self else { return }

               self.myArray.append("NewItem")
            
               self.myTableView.reloadData()
           }
        
        cell.didDelete = { [weak self] in
               guard let self = self else { return }

               
            self.myArray.remove(at:)
            
               self.myTableView.reloadData()
           }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        

           return cell

    }
    

    
    
}
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var buttonTapCallback: () -> ()  = { }
     var didDelete: () -> ()  = { }
    
    let button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return btn
    }()
    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
         let btn = UIButton()
         btn.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .green
         btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
         return btn
     }()
    
    let label: UILabel = {
       let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        lbl.textColor = .systemPink
       return lbl
    }()
    
    @objc func didTapButton() {
        buttonTapCallback()
    }
    
    @objc func didTapDelete() {
        didDelete()
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        //Add button
        contentView.addSubview(button)
                contentView.addSubview(deleteButton)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
           deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didDelete), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
   
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        //Set constraints as per your requirements
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        

        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        contentView.addSubview(deleteButton)
        //Set constraints as per your requirements
        deleteButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        deleteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        deleteButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        deleteButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your remove method is missing an index inside the didDelete callback: `self.myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)`Also, why are you using callbacks instead of just defining your buttons actions inside ViewController?

Comment: Give each cell or the delete button a unique identity so that you can delete the selected row through the cellForRowAt delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to use when delete

```
cell.label.text = ""
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

---

Then

```
 var didDelete: (Int) -> ()  = { }
```

with

```
 didDelete(button.tag)
```

and finally

```
cell.didDelete = { [weak self] tag in
   self.myArray.remove(at:tag) 
   self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: stating Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Int'

Answer (score 0):

In the cell declare the callback to pass the cell instance

```
var didDelete : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
```

and call it

```
didDelete?(self)
```

In the controller don't call `reloadData`, instead remove only the particular row. Another benefit is that the row is removed animated. In the closure get the index path from the table view cell

```
cell.didDelete = { aCell in
    let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)!
    self.myArray.remove(at: currentIndexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

`[weak self]` is not needed, the closure doesn't cause a retain cycle.

Comment: the code you suggest is causing a lot of compile errors. Thanks for you support. I have attached the GitHub link if you want to look https://github.com/redrock34/fetchfetch.

Comment: The code I suggest is not considered in your project. Please see the edit to make the closure optional

Comment: so you saying just use the cell.didDelete = { aCell in code?

Comment: Yes, in `cellForRowAt`, and the two other lines in the custom cell.

Comment: xcode is telling me I need to add a getting at selector ** #selector(getter: didDelete)**. I add the code and the code then causes a runtime error.

Comment: You are mixing up the delegate and the callback closure solution. If you use my suggestion you have to drop all code related to protocol/delegate

Comment: The only delegate I see is myTable.delegate is that it?